# XYFocusLeft/Right/Up/Down missing in Xamarin.UWP

Tags: xamarin.uwp, xbox, intellicode

In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/gamepad-and-remote-interactions, it is clearly stated that XYFocusLeft/Right/Up/Down can be used to manually determine the next focus using D-pad.  But these API are missing in Xamarin.UWP custom renderer.

I have made custom renderer for Button in Xamarin.UWP but I am not able to see these API in Visual Studio 2019 Intellicode.

These APIs should be shown in VS 2019 Intellicode and do not show as unknown API when it is typed in manually.

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you using? If c# you can try to train on your own code. IntelliCode does only provide recommendations on types for which it is trained.